# Remove all occurrences of charaters from an array from a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am building an application and will need to trim a fair amount of text from their inputs, I'd like to move the "removing" list into an array to make it easier to manage.

```
const badWords = ['jamie', 'hutber'];
const naughtyString = 'Jamie Hutber everybody likes Jamie Chocolate';
```

The expect output would be:

```
'everybody likes Chocolate'
```

So if its not clear, I'd like to remove all occurances that are in badWords from the string naughtySting...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was clear with the expect output would be. Is that more clear?

Comment: So loop over and do a replace()

Comment: Have you tried looping through the `badWords` removing any matches in `naughtyString`?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path, split your sentence to an array, remove all occurrences:

```
let goodSentence = naughtyString.split(' ').filter(s => badWords.indexOf(s.toLowerCase()) === -1).join(' ');
```

Comment: Ah filter... this was the stumbling block!!

Comment: Interesting idea as well, maybe a replace could work, in case the user wants to exclude `Jamie Hutber` but not `hutber` by itself :O

Answer (score 1):

If it's specifically for badWords, you can have something like this :

```
var result = naughtyString;
badWords.forEach(function(badWord){
     result = result.split(new RegExp(badWord,'i')).join(Array(badWord.length).join("*"));
});
```

> result == "**** ***** everybody likes **** Chocolate"

Answer (score 0):

Single iteration over the `badWords` :

```js
const badWords = ['jamie', 'hutber'];
let naughtyString = 'Jamie Hutber everybody likes Jamie Chocolate';

badWords.forEach(bad => {
     
  let rgx = new RegExp(bad, 'ig');
  naughtyString = naughtyString.replace(rgx, '');

});

console.log(naughtyString);
```

Comment: It's a single iteration over bad words, replaced with a multiple iteration over naughtyString..

Answer (score 0):

Another, more readable idea I came up with:

```js
const badWords = ['jamie', 'hutber'];
let naughtyString = 'Jamie Hutber everybody likes Jamie Chocolate';

const rgx = new RegExp(badWords.join('|'), 'gi');

let cleanString = naughtyString.replace(rgx, '');

console.log(cleanString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to check, case.. As your badwords are all lowercase, but your search string has mixed case.

```js
const badWords = ['jamie', 'hutber'];
const naughtyString = 'Jamie Hutber everybody likes Jamie Chocolate';

// 'everybody likes Chocolate'

function notBadWord(f) {
  return !badWords.includes(f.toLowerCase());
}

var out = naughtyString.split(/\s/).filter(notBadWord).join(" ");

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Ye, I don't get that either, but somebody also gave my question one and the other answer. Maybe he's just a guy who really really hates jS

Comment: @JamieHutber I assume the downvote on question could possibly be for zero visible effort. Just guessing though.

Comment: @Fran before an edit, he posted some not-working code

Comment: @wscourge  My edit was just to correct a spelling mistake.. :(

Comment: @Fran  How can it be zero effort, I even created a working Snippet, something some others haven't even bothered to do..

Comment: @Keith Did you ask the question? I referred to the question not your answer.

Comment: @Fran oops, sorry it's with it been a response on my answer,.. :)